# Is it possible/How to save Facebook Post ID to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a program (an app) which ask for user input then generate an image and post the image link to FB timeline. now i want to do is to get the POSTID and save it to my database. so i can have a record which i can retrieve if ever i want to connect to the FB POST. how can i do this? below is the code i use for posting to Facebook timeline.  Hope you can help me with this. My first time to do such thing. thanks a lot!

```
    $http_dir = 'http://site.com/Amats/image_entry/';
    $post_link = $http_dir . $img_newname;

    if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($office_id) && !empty($title) && !empty($story)) {

        $save_sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_contest` (filename, name, email, office_id, title, story, time) VALUES ('$img_newname','$name','$email','$office_id','$title','$story','$sql_date')";

        $query = mysql_query($save_sql,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database")); 

        if (mysql_num_rows($con) !== 0) { 
        header('Location:' . $uploadSuccess.'#modal-text'); 
        if($user_id) {

          // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
          try {
            $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                        array(
                                          'link' => $post_link,
                                          'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                                     ));
            echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

            // Give the user a logout link 
            echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
          } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                           'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                           )); 
            echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
          }   
        } else {

          // No user, so print a link for the user to login
          $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
          echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

        } 

        } 

        mysqli_close($con);
    }
```

I tried making something like this. but its not working;

```
        $post_id = $ret_obj['id'];
        $save_id = "INSERT INTO `tbl_mytable` (post_id) VALUES ('$post_id')";
        $query = mysql_query($save_id,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database"));
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Why using `mysql_*` functions? Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. which is another problem i think. I'll look into your links. but basically, am i doing the right way of getting the post id? thanks

Comment: my other queries linke inserting user input to database is fine. so i'm thinking if i'm doing something wrong with the way i get the facebook post id

Comment: @Pavan Kumar I dont get any error. the other details that should be saved to the database are being saved. only the POSTID is not being saved.

Comment: Try to print the $ret_obj and see whether you are getting the value for 'id'

Comment: isn't it the `echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';` ?

Comment: Yeah if you didn't got anything with that statement then there might be problem where you are getting the id. Try to checkout that one.

Comment: when I do `echo $ret_obj;` it gives me "Array" while in the `echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';` it prints `Post ID: 100000683716662_670529626313155` so how can i get and store the value of `$ret_obj['id']`?

Comment: ` $ret_obj['id']` is an array right? how do i get it's values passed to the database or to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

i think the code is like this:

```
$http_dir = 'http://site.com/Amats/image_entry/';
$post_link = $http_dir . $img_newname;

if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($office_id) && !empty($title) && !empty($story)) {

    $save_sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_contest` (filename, name, email, office_id, title, story, time) VALUES ('$img_newname','$name','$email','$office_id','$title','$story','$sql_date')";

    $query = mysql_query($save_sql,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database")); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($con) !== 0) { 
    header('Location:' . $uploadSuccess.'#modal-text'); 
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => $post_link,
                                      'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                                 ));
        echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

        //save post_id to MySQL
        $post_id = $ret_obj['id'];
        $save_id = "INSERT INTO `tbl_mytable` (post_id) VALUES ('$post_id')";
        $query = mysql_query($save_id,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database"));
        //save post_id to MySQL

        // Give the user a logout link 
        echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                       )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, so print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    } 

    } 

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

and you can create some functions to post FB.
i use curl to post FB, not use FB PHP SDK.
code

```
$arr['token'] = {your token};
$arr['content'] = {content};
$arr['url'] = {share url};

//save post_id to MySQL
$post_id = fb_post($arr);
$save_id = "INSERT INTO `mytable` (fb_id) VALUES ('$post_id')";
$query = mysql_query($save_id,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database"));
//save post_id to MySQL

function fb_post($post){
    $arr['url'] = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/";
    $arr['content'] = array(
        'access_token'=>$post['token'],
        'message' => $post['content'],
        'link' => $post['url']
    );
    $re = fb_post_c($arr);
    $temp = json_decode($re);
    return $temp->id;
}
function fb_post_c($arr){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $arr['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Expect:');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,http_build_query($arr['content']));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    $re = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $re;
}
```

with the fb php sdk

```
session_start();
require_once 'facebook.php';
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = {your appid};
$config['secret'] = {your secret};

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if($user_id){
    $_SESSION['token'] = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $arr['content'] = {content};
    $arr['url'] = {share url};
    $post_id = fb_post_c($arr);
    if($post_id){
        db_in($post_id);
        echo 'your post id' . $post_id;
    }
}else{
    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,user_activities',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://XXXXXXXXXXX/'
    );
    $facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
    echo "<a href ='".$loginUrl."'>login</a><br />";
}
function db_in($post_id){
    global $con;//your database ini
    $save_id = "INSERT INTO `mytable` (fb_id) VALUES ('$post_id')";
    $query = mysql_query($save_id,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database"));
}
function fb_post_c($arr){
    global $facebook;
    try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                    array(
                        'link' => $arr['url'],
                        'message' => $arr['content']
                    ));
        return $ret_obj['id'];
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @SamLaio what are the changes you made? I think you posted the same code. thanks :)

Comment: thanks you @SamLaio. I will try your code now. just have a quetion. isn't this `     try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => $post_link,
                                      'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                                 ));
        echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';` the code to post the lik on facebook? thanks

Comment: @Jben Kaye facebook can't post any HTML code, so your 'content' just like this 'i love fb with php', content is not like this '<b>i love fb with php</b>'

Comment: ok. but how about the other codes? can i just have all your codes paseted in my program? im having a bit hard time finding where to place those exactly.my php sdk is in the topmost of my program. i have some more codes at the below. i want the saving of the POSTID to be after this line: meaning the condition has to be true first. thank you again:

Comment: `        if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($office_id) && !empty($title) && !empty($story)) {
        
            $save_sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_contest` (filename, name, email, office_id, title, story, time) VALUES ('$img_newname','$name','$email','$office_id','$title','$story','$sql_date')";
        
            $query = mysql_query($save_sql,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database")); 
        
            if (mysql_num_rows($con) !== 0) { 
            header('Location:' . $uploadSuccess.'#modal-text');`

Comment: thank you uhm can you just edit my code in the question? because you gave me 3 sets of code i think. thank you i will let you know the result immediately. thanks again.

Comment: i think php try is catch, so out try Variable will clear. so you "insert database" code will in "try{", in first code 'save post_id to MySQL'

Comment: hi itried to paste the first set of code you gave. but it'e not posting on facebook. and not saving the POSTID to the dbase. thanks. now i'm going to try it again, but this time i will paste the second set of code below it.

Comment: post_id you can try '$ret_obj->id', fb return format is jason, so you need use json_decode

Comment: Hi @SamLaio here is the code i came up with. but it's not posting nor saving the POSTID. Hope you can help me further. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: i just edit your question. i put my code below yours so u can see it better. thank you

Comment: can i use something else? i dont know json_decode to be honest

Comment: you try 'print_r($ret_obj)', weatch fb api return any value

Comment: you can use phpinfo() for your host. i knew 5.0+ json is on. and fb sdk return mabe is var, you can print_r($ret_obj); then see return is any. i know curl is return json, you can try other code.

Comment: $con = mysql_connect("host","access","pw"); you seted?

Comment: yes my sql connection is fine. im working on your answer now.

Answer (score -1):

i'm trying to make something like this

```
        if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($office_id) && !empty($title) && !empty($story)) {

        $save_sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_contest` (filename, name, email, office_id, title, story, time) VALUES ('$img_newname','$name','$email','$office_id','$title','$story','$sql_date')";

        $query = mysql_query($save_sql,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database")); 

        if (mysql_num_rows($con) !== 0) { 
        header('Location:' . $uploadSuccess.'#modal-text'); 
        if($user_id) {

          // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
          // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
          try {
            $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                        array(
                                          'link' => $post_link,
                                          'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                                     ));
            echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

            // Give the user a logout link 
            echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
          } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
            // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
            // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
            // just ask the user to login again here.
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                           'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                           )); 
            echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
          }   
        } else {

          // No user, so print a link for the user to login
          // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_stream permission
          // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
          // need to specify it here.
          $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
          echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

        } 
        $get_id = $ret_obj['id'];
        $getid_sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_contest` (post_id) VALUES ('$get_id')";
        $getquery = mysql_query($getid_sql,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database"));
        } 


        mysqli_close($con);
    }
```

i just added these 3 lines to the previous code:

```
        $get_id = $ret_obj['id'];
        $getid_sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_contest` (post_id) VALUES ('$get_id')";
        $getquery = mysql_query($getid_sql,$con) or die(mysql_error("Could not write information to the database"));
```